# "Void" type not allowed here (Java)

Tags: java

I have 2 class the EmpresaTest(Main) and the Empresa. When I save the return statement of a metod, is returned a error: "Void type not allowed here". I noticed in some foruns that could be 'cause the metod is "void" type, but, in this case, is not void, it is boolean.

Código/CODE: [Código - Error](http://pastebin.com/i7utpwwv)

Comment: Welcome, I know it's a pain and I'm truly very sorry, but this is a English based forum

Comment: You are looking for http://pt.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Check out pt.stackoverflow.com too

Comment: @Blorgbeard eddited post

Comment: Can you post only the relevant code? (The part with the error)

Comment: @MarcoAcierno the error is in just line 25            t = Booelan.parseBoolean(e1.adicionaEmpregado(f1));
        System.out.println("T: " + t);

Comment: You mispelled Boolean: it should be 

t = Boolean.parseBoolean(e1.adicionaEmpregado(f1));

Comment: @nem sry! But i want to save the return result on the variable T. The method  boolean contemFuncionario(Funcionario f) returns me the valor of func. But Why i can't save this valor on T?

Comment: Look at @MadProgrammer's answer

Comment: @JacquelineCosta Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's good to see that your problem has been solved, but the way to show that is to either click the checkmark next to the answer that helped you, or to "answer your own question" and click the checkmark next to your answer if you figured it out on your own.

Answer (score 3):

`adicionaEmpregado` is declared as `void`, meaning it does not returning anything...

```
public void adicionaEmpregado(Funcionario f) {
```

This means that it can't be used in this situation...

```
t = Booelan.parseBoolean(e1.adicionaEmpregado(f1));
```

As it makes no sense, the method returns nothing...

Either, you will need to change the method to return a `String` or provide another method which can return the result of the current state accordingly...

Comment: You're sure! I changed the method ;x the correct is        t = e1.contemFuncionario(f1);

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

The problem was I was declaring a method that not returns nothing.

```
    t = Booelan.parseBoolean(e1.adicionaEmpregado(f1));
    System.out.println("T: " + t);
```

Changed to

```
    t = e1.contemFuncionario(f1);
    System.out.println("T: " + t);
```